# Regex pattern help for phrase OR a character set

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP regex that I want to fail if the matched word after `/blog` is just `feed`.

This MUST be done within the regex itself, not using any other PHP syntax.

The regex currently looks like this:

```
blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

What would I add to this to properly negate the regex if `feed` is found after `blog/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
'/^blog\/(?!feed$)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$/'
```

Comment: Isn't `feed\\b` more appropriate than `feed$` in this case?

Comment: @Amarghosh, you might be correct, but I wasn't sure he is matching a url or extracting urls from the text/html. So, @andybaird, If you need to extract that kind of urls from text/html data, you could remove anchors `^` and `$` s, and put `\\b` (word boundary) instead of `$`

Comment: Thanks Mark, I ended up implementing: blog/(?!feed\b)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
Which worked perfectly.